# How to open different contents in the different pop up window

Tags: html

```
<html>    
<script type="text/javascript">
     function openWin(url) {
            window.open(url, "_blank", "toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, top=200, left=300, width=870, height=650");
        }    
    </script>


        <a href = "javascript:openWin('c.html')">Content 2</a>
        <a href = "javascript:openWin('b.html')">Content 3</a>
    </html>`
```

this is my code to open to javascript popup. but when i click content 2 only one popup should open ` but here instead multiple popups are opening. and also parallely content 3 window should open in a diff window.

Comment: Your HTML sample looks broken. Maybe something went wrong while copy and pasting the source?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to supply javascript on the `href` attribute, instead use onclick.

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openWin('c.html')">Content 2</a>`.

Also, you are missing some necessary tags in your HTML document. You are missing the required `body` tag for example. You can check your document for syntax and to some extend semantic errors by using the [W3C HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/).